# Lib.Web.Mvc rename submit cancel buttons and form caption

Tags: jqgrid, lib.web.mvc

I am using the Lib.Web.MVC library for integrating the free jqgrid to mvc.  When I open the edit or add dialog form from the grid, I want to rename the submit and cancel buttons and also the form caption.

In the jqgrid this was done using bSubmit, bCancel, addcaption, editCaption properties.  How can I do this using Lib.Web.MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of Lib.Web.Mvc those values are being taken from the jqGrid language script file, you can overwrite the defaults in JavaScript (for example just before caling the helper `GetJavaScript()` method):

```
$.jgrid.edit.addCaption = "Add Record";
$.jgrid.edit.editCaption = "Edit Record";
$.jgrid.edit.bSubmit = "Submit";
$.jgrid.edit.bCancel = "Cancel";
```